# changing self typing text via select button not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html-select

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexThunders/k8s79zL5/18/

I'm trying to change self typing text from English to Russian when I click option in select:

```
  let engType = [
    'Never give up. ',
     'You can win. '
  ]
  
  let rusType = [
    'Никогда не сдавайся. ',
    'Ты можешь победить. '
  ]
```

page is loaded and this function gradually types letters:

```
  function typeCharacters(phrases) {
    if(phrases[count] !== undefined && phrases[count] !== null && phrases[count] !== "") {
      let allLength  = phrases[count].length
      setInterval(() => {
        if(phrases[count] !== undefined && typePar !== null) {
          character = phrases[count].slice(ind,ind+1)
          txt = document.createTextNode(character)
          typePar.appendChild(txt)
          ind++
          let typeLength = typePar.textContent.length
          if(typeLength === allLength) {
            count++
            ind = 0
            if(phrases[count] !== undefined) {
              allLength += phrases[count].length
            }
          } 
        }
      },100)
    }
  }
  typeCharacters(engType)
```

It works. But when I merely touch select button without even choosing language, I get nonsense paragraph with mixed letters in one or in both languages within the same paragraph:

```
  function searchLang(choosenLang) {
    //if choosen language coincides with one in Object:
    if(languages[choosenLang]) {
      allDataElements.forEach(element => {
        //every property of choosen object/language
        for(let x in languages[choosenLang]) {
          //compare with element's data attribute
          if(element.getAttribute('data') === x) {
            //the same attribute changes iinerText in accordance with object
            element.innerText = languages[choosenLang][x]
            if(languages[choosenLang].changePhrases !== undefined) {
              languages[choosenLang].changePhrases(choosenLang)
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
  
  select.addEventListener('click', () => {
    allLangOptions.forEach(option => {
      if(option.selected === true) {
        let lang = option.value
        searchLang(lang)
      }
    })
  })
```

and the result:

```
Никeгда не сд.вайся. Тыuможешь по едить. OR

Никогда нe up. айс
```

However for other html elements select button works right: only when I choose option but not click select itself.

I use changePhrases functions in object to change language in typing paragraph:

```
let languages = {
    en: {
        mPheadLIabout: 'About',
        mPheadLIprojects: 'Projects',
        mPheadLIcontacts: 'Contacts',
        changePhrases: function() {
          if(typePar !== null) {
            typePar.textContent = "";
            count = 0
            ind = 0
            typeCharacters(engType)
          }
        }
      },
    ru: {
        mPheadLIabout: 'О сайте',
        mPheadLIprojects: 'Проекты',
        mPheadLIcontacts: 'Контакты',
        changePhrases: function() {
          if(typePar !== null) {
            typePar.textContent = "";
            count = 0
            ind = 0
            typeCharacters(rusType)
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

At first paragraph clears itself, and begins to type from first character as indicated above.

I've tried to use variable reset to stop invoking typing English characters but unsuccessfully.

Also I've applied different variants with setTimeout and promise for case when paragraph is cleared and only then you run function typeCharacters(rusType). Still not working and no errors in console.

And the same result I get with English.

Looks like when I click select button(not options) it again fires function to type text, not waits till I use options. And when I click option it fires to times simultaneously.

Here is the entire code and weird result:

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexThunders/k8s79zL5/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding an event handler to the `click` event, you should only fire the callback when a user changes the selected option of a `select` element. So the event type should be `change`:

```js
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  allLangOptions.forEach((option) => {
    if (option.selected === true) {
      let lang = option.value;
      searchLang(lang);
    }
  });
});
```

This way you can also use your keyboard to change the options. Although keyboard users could change the language option, as this is not a mouse click, your `click` event would not fire and the callback inside your `addEventListener` would not run. Make sure you always hook to the `change` event of the `select` element.

Another problem is that you never cancel the interval. When you select a language, it just starts another timer which just messes up everything. It will look like the effect is sped up, the text become gibberish as the different characters are getting mixed, etc.

To avoid this, you need to save the interval ID returned from `window.setInterval()` and cancel it when you run `typeCharacters()`:

```js
// ...
let reset = false;
// create a variable in an outer scope
let activeInterval = null;

function typeCharacters(phrases) {
  // clear running interval
  clearInterval(activeInterval);

  if (reset) return;
  if(phrases[count] !== undefined
    && phrases[count] !== null
    && phrases[count] !== "") {
    let allLength  = phrases[count].length

    // save the interval ID
    activeInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if(phrases[count] !== undefined && typePar !== null) {
      // ... rest of your code
```

Comment: And thanks for explanation about 'change'. I've had no idea about existence of this event....still learning

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it works fine now. If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)? It may help more people who have similar issue.